# how can i make dynamic layout using media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I've been trying to make a few layouts for specific sizes.

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I tried to create two layouts, PC and mobile.

Making a PC was easy. `SectionA` and `SectionB` were configured through the `flex` layout, and `SectionC` was configured below it.

The problem was with Mobile. `SectionA` and `SectionB` are tied together in a flex layout, so I couldn't think of a way to put `SectionC` between `A` and `B`.

This is because, in the html structure, `sectionC` already exists below. Is it possible to configure only with CSS without using Javascript?

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*only for ilustration*/
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*only for ilustration*/
  background-color: #ffd5d5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .bottom {
    flex-direction: column;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header">
    <div>
      SectionA
    </div>
    <div>
      SectionB
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    SectionC
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML and CSS that you already have

Comment: `order` property will help you here. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Comment: @VictorSantizo sorry i update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have just made a change in your HTML.
- So I wrapped all div inside of `.header`.
- Then, to give 50% width for first to direct child I have just added class `.hlalf` and set this class CSS to `flex:1 0 50%`, which means take 50% width of flexbox.
- Now to achieve bottom div in center in responsive we use `order` property of flexbox. and for that I have just added class to all 3 div according to their order. I have used **sm** keyword just for understanding as small screens.

```css
    @media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
      .order-sm-1 {
        order: 1;
      }
      .order-sm-2 {
        order: 2;
      }
      .order-sm-3 {
        order: 3;
      }
    }
```

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.header>div.half {
  /*This css tells all the direct div of header class to take 50% of the space*/
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.bggreen {
  background: green;
}

.bgblue {
  background: blue;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #ffd5d5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*This will change flex-direction to column which is by default row*/
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .order-sm-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .order-sm-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .order-sm-3 {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="bggreen half order-sm-1">
      SectionA
    </div>
    <div class="bgblue half order-sm-3">
      SectionB
    </div>
    <div class="bottom order-sm-2">
      SectionC
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your section in a flex container and play with the flex-order properties

Comment: is it worng answer?? when i try to flex order. this issue can be fixed. but, is it any good better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party with this one but Grid's the way to go in my opinion as you get complete control over where you put items. It's much more versatile than flexbox but it is a steep learning curve initially as there are so many options. Kevin Powell has a good introductory [video](https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU) to grid and [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is also a good, clearly-written resource from css tricks.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "a b" "c c";
  border: 2px solid #285DBB;
  row-gap: 0.25rem;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  padding: 0.35rem;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #92D050;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  padding: 0.75rem 2rem;
}

.zoneA {
  grid-area: a;
  text-decoration: underline wavy red;
}

.zoneB {
  grid-area: b;
}

.zoneC {
  grid-area: c;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

.pc {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:760px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "a" "c" "b";
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .pc {
    display: none;
  }
  .zoneB {
    text-decoration: underline wavy red;
  }
  .zoneC {
    text-decoration: underline wavy red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="zoneA">
    SectionA
  </div>
  <div class="zoneB">
    SectionB
  </div>
  <div class="zoneC">
    SectionC
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pc footer">PC</div>
<div class="mobile footer">Mobile</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<meta content="width=device-width,height=device-height,inital-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.